# Python socket with methods

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to create a simple server that receiving an option and returning a method.

So I looked for a few examples and I found this one:

```
def start_server(ip="0.0.0.0", port=8820):
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind((ip, port))
    sock.listen(1)
    print "Server started listening on %s:%d" % (ip, port)

    return sock


def new_client(sock):
    c_sock, c_addr = sock.accept()
    print "got new client %s" % c_addr

    return c_sock, c_addr
```

How do I create the start server and client calls?

I want the client to send an option and the server return the method
with a loop that ends in call the quit method.

like an example method if the client pressed "name":

```
def get_name():
    return "My name is Server!"
```

thanks!

Comment: you can use `socketserver` https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html (and there are nice examples)

Comment: thanks but It won't help me to understand where I should put the while-True loop (in the client or the server?) 
and how to call correct for the methods

Comment: build normal web server and you will have less troubles. you can use `flask`, `bottle`, `django`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample that creates an "echo" server. (It just sends all the data it gets from a client back to the client.)

Add this to the end of your existing code:

```
import select
def main():
    lsock = start_server()
    rfds=[lsock]
    while True:
        readyfds, _, _ = select.select(rfds, [], [])
        for fd in readyfds:
            if fd == lsock:
                csock, caddr = new_client(lsock)
                rfds.append(csock)
            else:
                rdata = fd.recv(1024)
                if rdata:
                    print("Got some data from client socket %s" % fd)
                    # Send data back to client
                    fd.send(rdata)
                else:
                    print("Client socket closed %s" % fd)
                    rfds.remove(fd)
                    fd.close()

main()
```

Annotation: We are using `select` here to allow a single thread to wait on multiple file descriptors at once. Whenever a connection request comes in from a client, the listening socket becomes "ready"; we then accept the connection and add the new socket to the set of descriptors in our selection list.

When we receive data from any other socket, we call `recv`. If that succeeds, we send the same data back to the client (obviously a real server would do something more useful with the data). If the `recv` returns zero, that means the client closed the socket, so then we remove the descriptor from the selection list.

One more thing: In the line `print "got new client %s" % c_addr`, `c_addr` is a tuple (address and port), hence the formatting fails due to `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. Easy fix is to make it: `print "got new client %s" % str(c_addr)`